# local git remote repo lost master branch

Tags: git

After looking through the SO answers, I cannot find anything that comes close to what I think my problem is right now.

Being fairly new to git, I started a new project by following some of the newby recommendations.

My setup: a local NAS has the original master git repo, started by adding code from a directory with code not under git control. Using TortoiseGit (TG) I added the base code and kept modifying, compiling and committing to the local repo and then pushing to the NAS repo.

Initially, all went the way all of the tutorials show, but at one point I wanted to create a branch to test code meant to resolve a specific issue, which kept going for some time and became the de facto master branch.
Somewhere along the line I wanted to merge this back into the master, but I made some bad choices, it seems, and now neither my supposed master nor my local repo any longer has any master branch and only one branch named Branch_new.

While in theory I assume I could just carry on on this mislabeled branch, I would prefer to get back to a more conventional setup.

At this stage it is not very important that I keep all of the history and I could simply start over by pretending that the current code is my initial base, but as part of learning a bit more about the git way of doing things, I would prefer to learn how to extricate myself from the mess things are in.

TIA

Comment: the only way to loos a branch is to intentionally delete it. Did you do it? Also, how do you know that there is no master branch any longer? did you do `git branch --list`? If you deleted the branch, there is a reflog which you can possibly look through and find out the history of your master branch.

Comment: @Serge did you mean “lose”?

Comment: oops, yes, i meant 'to lose'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not everything is lost. By default, git cleans up commits which are not referenced by any branch only after two weeks (see `git help gc`). If two weeks have not passed, then you might recover your work.
Now getting to find these commits might get a bit tricky. There are different methods to achieve this, I like the reflog best. You can access it by either `git reflog` command, or looking at the raw file under `.git/logs/HEAD`, which will show you all the places (commits) that you've been at, and the command that made git switch to that commit or branch.
Once you find your commit, recreating a branch from it (to save it from garbage collection) is as simple as `git branch <branch_name> <commit>`. You can verify the history beforehand by `git log <commit>`, as all commits point to their ancestor, so you'll have the complete history up to that point.

As for what caused the mess you encountered, I cannot be sure without the reflog and the history of all your commands, starting from initializing the repository. I did find, however, that most problems with new remotes happen due to the remote not being a bare repository (which sounds like the case from what you describe). Remotes that you push to need to be bare, i.e. not have a working directory, but only the git metadata (whatever a regular clone will usually have under `.git/`). That's because pushing to a repo which has a branch checked out does make a mess.
When initializing a repo that you want to act as a remote (so you can push to it), you should make it bare. Read a bit more on `git init --bare` or `git clone --bare`, these should get you started setting up a remote correctly.
Note that even if a repo is not bare, you can still clone from it. This causes most of the confusion around pushing to new repos.

Comment: thank you,  I'm afraid, some of the history is more than 2 weeks old, what with time away & time spend trying to research & recover from the problem. Looks like I might as well start over, particularly since I have come to another point where I will likely have to branch, if not actually a fork to take a new approach.

Comment: As a follow up & after some reflection, is there a way to simply rename the lone remote ( & local) 'branch' to make it the 'master'?

Comment: `git branch -m ` will rename the branch.

Comment: The commits might be more than two weeks, but have they been “unreachable” from a branch for two weeks?

Comment: Not really sure how I would make sure; if I understand your question 'correctly', yes, the last time I tried to get to 'master' was more than 2 weeks ago; meanwhile I was busy fixing and committing for a while until I realized 'master' was gone.

Comment: git garbage collection won't delete `master`, or any other branch for that matter. The fact that you didn't check it out does not mean it's all gone just yet. What gc does is delete the commits that do not make up history of any branch. So for example, if your new branch was based off of master, your work is still there. But if you had different work on master and on your branch, then somehow master got deleted and it's been over two weeks, it is likely that the work that was forked off in master is lost. You should try using the reflog, sounds like you have nothing to lose.

Comment: @user999713 The question and answer do have two parts. Even if you choose not to check the reflog, did my reply about bare repositories help at all?

Comment: @micromoses my apologies for the delay - I was off chasing hardware issues on another machine. I have lloked at the rteflogs on the 'master' machine, but I see nothing. FWIW, I am using the context menu from Tortoisegit. Reflog for the working directory does show some entries, back to a clone some 19 commits before the current state, it does not go back to master nor is there any mention of it
Regarding the bare repo, I am not really sure what or how I would  check. I can clone from the bare 'master' repo, but the revision graph shows no reference to a master branch.